# Package not listed in requirements warnings in PyCharm

Tags: pip, pycharm

PyCharm checks that every imported module (not in the standard lib) is in `requirements.txt` but for some modules (eg: `grpcio` vs `grpc`), the package name is different from the module name. Is there a way to silence the warnings in this case?

Answer (score 11):

It's the bug in PyCharm, and it's still open: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11963

You can use #noinspection PyPackageRequirements to each import with this warning to suppress it.

Comment: I have this issue with version 2018.1 and the `serial` module provided by `pyserial` package.

Comment: I have this issue with tensorflow in 2018.2.

Comment: I have this problem for all packages where the module name differs from the package name, so for example if I import "auditlog.registry" from the "django-auditlog" package, the module will not be recognized.